# Break template in more than one file in vue, with out make any new components

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

My template is too long(about 900 lines).I want to break it into two or three html files but I don’t want to make any new components! because create component, forces me to sync a few elements and its too hard! is there any way to do this? Just to give a better sense.

Comment: A root component with some components inside is your best. Maybe you dont like it but its the better way in vue. And why have you got problems to sync the elements?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `render` function in vue. see the document below

[vue render document](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html)

but in my opinion creating new components is much better!